# Mac OSX can not delete anaconda3 folder

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall Anaconda 3 from my macbook but when i do

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

it won't delete the folder saying

```
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0/share/terminfo/71: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0/share/terminfo: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0/share: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3/lib: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/myuser/anaconda3: Directory not empty
```

also when I start a new installation, it won't let me by saying Anaconda is already installed. I'm stuck.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la ~/anaconda3/pkgs`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser  staff   96  3 Mar 12:38 ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0